# Clarify difference between first order and second order Monte Carlo simulation

Tags: simulation, terminology, monte-carlo

What is the qualitative difference between a first and second order Monte Carlo simulation, and the context in which one would implement each?

Comment: Where have you found that terminology?

Comment: @ocram - I have seen it in health economic and medical trial literature.  [Here, for example.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10929854)

Comment: Pages 196-197 of this [document](http://www.med.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/courses/EPIB654/Summer2010/Uncertainty/Koerkamp_2010_Patient%20heterogeneity.pdf) might be of interest. These seem to be part of the medical statistics jargon.

Comment: I found this article helpful: Jain R, Grabner M, Onukwugha E. Sensitivity analysis in cost-effectiveness studies: from guidelines to practice. Pharmacoeconomics. 2011 Apr;29(4):297-314. doi: 10.2165/11584630-000000000-00000.

Answer (score 1):

The paper [1] at the link given by user10525 uses those two terms in the following way:

- first order simulation takes account of process variability
- second order simulation additionally takes account of parameter uncertainty

From a bit of looking around these terms seem to crop up in medical and health literature.

While this first-order/second-order naming scheme doesn't seem to be as widely used outside the health area, the distinction and concepts are certainly widespread. (I think they're reasonable terms, but I'll probably stick to explicitly discussing the distinction myself.)

(One wonders if they'd then count incorporating model uncertainty as "third order")

[1]: Groot KB, Weinstein MC, Stijnen T, Heijenbrok-Kal MH, Hunink MG (2010),
"Uncertainty and patient heterogeneity in medical decision models."
*Med Decis Making*, Mar-Apr;30(2):194-205.
doi: 10.1177/0272989X09342277.